# shopialfb integration as part of default installation

Tags: magento2, installation, integration

Today I installed a fresh install of Magento 2.2.0 after downloading the zip from the magento site. After installing I got the following error message.

[image]

After a bit of investigating I found this is due to shopialfb facebook module which is apparently part of the core magento download.

Clicking this message takes me to the integrations page where I can see the integration for this module. I cannot delete this integration but I can activate it which appears to give it access to my categories and products.

I have three questions about this module

1. Is there a way to disable this error message without giving this module access? Or disable the module entirely without breaking core functionality?
2. Does activating this integration pose some sort of security risk? Many of the products on my clients store are being sold directly to other businesses and should not be visible to the public.
3. Why has this module become part of core? I am sure it has it's uses but it seems very much the sort of thing I would look for an extension for. I am not sure why it has been included as part of core.

Comment: IMHO, It looks like an unfair marketing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To uninstall the module you can run:

```
sudo -u www-data php bin/magento module:uninstall Shopial_Facebook
```

*Note: change the `www-data` to corresponding user name of your server.*

**Nothing in magento depends on this module, so it should work as usually.**

Result should looks like this:

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-31-155:/var/www/html$ sudo -u www-data php bin/magento module:uninstall Shopial_Facebook
>
> You are about to remove code and/or database tables. Are you sure?[y/N]y
>
> Enabling maintenance mode
>
> You are about to remove a module(s) that might have database data. Do you want to remove the data from database?[y/N]y
>
> You are removing data without a database backup. No data to clear in Shopial_Facebook
>
> Removing Shopial_Facebook from module registry in database
>
> Removing Shopial_Facebook from module list in deployment configuration
>
> Removing code from Magento codebase:
>
> Cache cleared successfully.
>
> Generated classes cleared successfully.
>
> Please run the 'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes.
>
> Info:
>
> Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. To do this, run 'module:uninstall' with the --clear-static-content option to clear them.
>
> Disabling maintenance mode

**PS: IMHO, It looks like an unfair marketing**